# Make an image change iframes page

Tags: html, iframe

I have a page with an iframe in it and want an image on the main page to load another page in the iframe. I think I should use a target for the link but I'm not too sure.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('testId').src = 'http://www.yahoo.com'"><img src="myImage.jpg"/></a>
    <iframe id="testId" width=100 height=100 src="http://www.google.com" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The 'target' attribute is generally used for opening in a new window/tab or targeting an existing one.  Communication between frames and windows is best done via javascript.

Comment: Thanks, that appeared to do it!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="example.html" target="myframe"><img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<iframe name="myframe" src="test.html"></iframe>
```